# System Tray Notifications: Are they standard windows or Owner Drawn Popup Menus or other?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Are notification/alert windows (that appear above the Windows System Tray) like the examples below just a standard window, owner drawn `HMENU`'s  or are they implemented using [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? *Note*: I know that the actual system tray icon is implemented using `NOTIFYICONDATA`, but are the notification windows also implemented using this structure?

In my WinAPI C++ application I want to show a similar notification where it will appear above the system tray icon, have buttons, horizontal scroll bars and etc. I know I can just create a new HWND, position it above the system tray and show that but if there is a specific WinAPI 'System Tray Notification' class/function I would prefer to use that, thus my question.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are notification/alert windows (that appear above the Windows System Tray) like the examples below just a standard window, owner drawn HMENU's or are they implemented using NOTIFYICONDATA?

These are *custom* dialogs displayed when needed.  They are *not* implemented using `NOTIFYICONDATA`.  You can use [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378426.aspx) to get the current location of your tray icon when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Tray notifications are all about *notifying* the process that owns the icon that a click event has occurred so it can then do its thing, whatever that may be.

There is no specialised mechanism or framework for anything GUI related in this case.

> [Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx): When a user right-clicks the icon, it should
>   bring up a normal shortcut menu. However, the result of a single 
>   click with the left mouse button will vary with the function of the 
>   icon. *It should display what the user would expect to see in the form 
>   best suited to that content—a popup window, a dialog box or the program 
>   window itself. For instance, it could show status text for a status icon,
>   or a slider for the volume control.*

Comment: No, "a notification informs users of events that are unrelated to the current user activity", it's the user who is notified not the process. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742472.aspx

Comment: Yes, from the UX perspective. Try notifying a user without a process.

Comment: The important thing about notifications is that they notify the user. Otherwise, there's nothing that makes a notification different from, say, a button control. Both of them notify a process that a click event occurred.